# How to spin the ec2 from Ami(with multiple volumes -3+) using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to spin ec2 from AMI and AMI which has 4 volumes using terraform.
Any pointers is much appreciated?

```
resource "aws_instance" "this" {
count = var.instance_count
ami                           = var.ami_id
instance_type                 = var.instance_type
key_name                      = var.key_name
iam_instance_profile          = var.iam_instance_profile 
disable_api_termination       = var.enable_deletion_protection    
user_data                     = var.user_data

network_interface { 
  network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.eth0[count.index].id
  device_index = 0
}

dynamic "root_block_device" {
    for_each = var.root_block_device
    content {
    delete_on_termination = lookup(root_block_device.value, "delete_on_termination", true)
    encrypted             = lookup(root_block_device.value, "encrypted", null)
    iops                  = lookup(root_block_device.value, "iops", null)
    kms_key_id            = lookup(root_block_device.value, "kms_key_id", null)
    volume_size           = lookup(root_block_device.value, "volume_size", null)
    volume_type           = lookup(root_block_device.value, "volume_type", null)
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question, not the comments.

Comment: Please add `root_block_device` variable with any values you are providing.

Comment: Also, are there any errors with the current code? If so, please add that to the question as well.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I understood what the question was. I don't think you can have more than one root block device. However, you can have multiple EBS block devices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Want to spin ec2 from AMI and AMI which has 4 volumes using terraform

Then you don't need to do anything. The EBS volumes are already associated to the AMI with the *block device mappings*. Any instance launched from that AMI will automatically be spun up with the 4 ebs volumes.

More on block device mappings:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html

Comment: The question was asked from the perspective of how to accomplish the task via Terraform.  The primary advantage of provisioning resources via Terraform is so that those resources can be fully managed via Terraform.  By doing nothing (i.e. not defining those block devices in the terraform), Terraform will have no knowledge of the additional volumes, and thus are unable to be managed via Terraform.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer post your answer then?